# Anybody have a clever idea to create a system wide override to force text editing shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, shortcut

macOS defaults to a handful of convenient text editing shortcuts such as:

- ^e moving the cursor to the end of lin
- ^k deleting all characters after the cursor until the end of the line
- ^a moving the cursor to the beginning of the line
- etc

I LOVE these shortcuts. I don't want anything in macOS to ever override them. I'm trying to figure out the most painless way to force them to behave as they are supposed to by some combination of BetterTouchTool/Alfred/Karabiner override and following action via some AppleScript...script but I haven't figured out a good route yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain one time when these don’t work? I may be not understanding the failure scenario causing the request. All macOS shortcuts are in the keyboard pane so you either have an os override you can fix or no os override from my understanding.

Comment: Microsoft Excel/Outlook and "Anki" set their own shortcuts. For example, pushing ctrl+d in Anki adds a capitalized "D" to the text instead of forward delete. I'm looking for a way to either override this at a low level (Karabiner) or a high level (Aflred/BTT) or some other means.

Comment: So you’re talking about third party text input. Probably not in the cards, but let’s see. You might need to edit the post if it gets closed with those details